# Firefox temporary files in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, firefox, temporary-files

When using Firefox in OS X where are the temporary files stored?

Answer (score 3):

Firefox stores temporary files in

`/Users/<profile name>/Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/<something>.default/Cache/`.

Firefox also uses

`/Users/<profile name>/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/...`,

and in case you're interested, Flash uses

`/Users/<profile name>/Macromedia/Flash\ Player/...`.

I recommend the free program [fseventer](http://download.cnet.com/fseventer/3000-2094_4-78566.html) if you want to know more about where programs store/change files.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In Mac, Profile folders are in one of these locations:

- `~/Library/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/<profile folder>`
- `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<profile folder>`

The tilde character (~) refers to the current user's Home folder, so `~/Library` is the `/Macintosh HD/Users/<username>/Library` folder.

Look for Cache folder under your Profile folder.

Alternatively, type in `about:cache` in Firefox's address bar and hit Enter. There you will see the full paths of memory/disk/offline cache directories.

Comment: Didn't find the first directory.

Comment: Then it must be in the second one. What about it?